# Is there a best practice for only partially integrating a PHP framework in a sub-directory of a website?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I hope this question isn't to broad or subjective, but what I am looking for is whether there is (or are) well-established ways in to implement a Laravel framework within an existing website.

We are currently using a custom CMS for our site, which covers 95% of our needs. However, I'd like to make a sub-directory of which all of *it's* sub-directories implement Laravel. My concern is that I'm not entirely sure how the inner-workings of Laravel's Routing works (and I'm not sure whether or not our CMS does its own routing behind the scenes as well), so I wouldn't want to have conflicting URI issues of our CMS stepping on Laravel's toes and vice versa.

I'm only slightly familiar with the .htaccess rules, but would that (a separate .htaccess in the Laravel sub-directory) be the key to implementing Laravel's Routing beginning at that folder down, and not for any of the other pages on the site? And if our CMS does do its own routing, would the lower-level .htaccess override the higher-level one?

Does any of this raise any red flags on problems that could arise later in development?

Comment: could you put this extension on a sub-domain instead of a sub-folder?

Comment: I think it could be a possibility. I just talked to our network guy about that, and he mentioned that it the trade-off of the benefits of Laravel might be outweighed by the overhead of having to maintain an additional subdomain (which I admit I know very little about)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think routing will be a problem (Laravel normally works pretty well in a subdirectory from routing perspective). If you use the URL helpers of Laravel you're all good.

The more serious problem with Laravel in a subdirectory is security. To avoid your whole framework code being accessible to the everyone you will need to break the `public` directory and the rest of the framework apart.

I suggest this structure:

```
- laravel_app
--- app
--- bootstrap
--- vendor
--- ...
- document_root
--- your cms stuff
--- laravel     (laravel "public" directory renamed to whatever url you want it under)
------ index.php
------ .htaccess
------ assets
```

To make this work you have to edit two files:

#### `public/index.php` (now `document_root/laravel/index.php`)

```
require __DIR__.'/../../laravel_app/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../laravel_app/bootstrap/start.php';

$app->run();
```

#### `app/bootstrap/paths.php` (now `laravel_app/app/bootstrap/paths.php`)

```
// ...
'public' => __DIR__.'/../../document_root/laravel',
// ...
```

Comment: This all sounds great. That was definitely another concern, where to keep Laravel's files, and then how to reconfigure it based on the new locations, so this answers a lot of my concerns. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you need some more information. As I already said, routing shouldn't be a problem either. Any other concerns? ;)