# Partially integrating the Laravel Framework in select sub-directories of a main website

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, laravel, frameworks

I recently asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27967050/is-there-a-best-practice-for-only-partially-integrating-a-php-framework-in-a-sub) and received some great answers, but I'm realizing that it wasn't quite the right question.

We currently use a CMS that fulfills 95% of our needs on our site, however for that extra 5% I'd like to bring in a PHP Framework for things like Form Processing/Validation, Authentication, etc. My original question was if it would be possible to have a single sub-directory within our site that could manage all of those projects. But now I'm realizing that this method would need everything to be in something like a .../projects URI, breaking a pretty good REST setup we have now with the CMS (the only routing I'd want to have to manage is within my own applications, not the entire site to work around this).

Is it possible to have Laravel's main folder at the root directory, and only include it in specific sub-directories or files that I want. I imagine it something like just having multiple `public` folders, which I'm not sure if it's possible/reccommended? I also imagine I would have to essentially turn of Laravel's Routing so that it doesn't step on the toes of the CMS, but I believe I could turn it back on for each folder with each having its own `.htaccess`?

I picture the architecture looking sort of like this:

```
         root
        /   \
      html  laravel
      /   \
     ...   [normal page]
    /   \              \
   /     \              [project] 
[project] [normal page]
```

I've read a little that the Zend Framework is made especially for partial integration like this, in which case if it's better suited for the job, I could definitely switch over. But it'd be great if it'd be possible with Laravel since I'm already fairly comfortable with the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this fairly easily. The basic steps include:

- Modify your .htaccess or vhost files so that each location hosted by Laravel points to Laravel's public/index.php. You'll need to put these more specific rules first, as Apache will follow the first matching rule that it finds.
- [Optional] If you want to change the folder structure of your Laravel project, modify the files in the bootstrap folder (paths.php, autoload.php, and start.php) to point to the correct paths, and make sure that public/index.php (or wherever you put it) can find the autoload and start files.
- That should be it. Make sure that your Laravel routes reference the full path.

Unfortunately, this approach does mean you'll need to add a rewrite rule for each Laravel route you want to add. This way, Laravel won't interfere with your CMS's routing; it will only handle requests that get rewritten to go to index.php. You just have to make sure that the rewrite rules have higher priority by putting them before the general rewrite rules for your CMS.

Comment: Thank you very much. That sounds like it could work. Is there a benefit to using .htaccess over vhost or vice versa?

Comment: I generally prefer to use vhost as it allows you to keep all of your configuration in one location; .htaccess is on a per-directory basis. But this approach should work with either method.